# Why is it so difficult to create subfolders in mac's finder

Tags: mac-osx

In Finder, in list view, why can't i just right click on a file and "Create new folder".  Instead, I must file new -> new folder (or hot key).  And when I do, the new folder is not even created in the directory that I asked it to be in, it puts it in the root of everything.

I really want to know why Mac doesn't support this.  Are there any other solutions for doing this in finder?

Comment: SHould this not be on SuperUser?

Comment: Yeah... my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the keyboard shortcut? Command-Shift-N. If you have an item selected in the Finder and invoke the shortcut you will get a new folder at the same level of the item you had selected. The input focus will be in the "rename" field for the folder you just created, so just type the name and hit Return.

Comment: But it doesn't create it at the same level for me or the other machine I just tested it on.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? Is it a regular folder on a local disk?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a folder,

click on the folder above where you want it created..

(As in saying, insert a new folder into the folder you are clicking on..)

This is how i do it..